# Time evolution of spin with Anti-symmetric (Dzyaloshinkii-Moriya) interaction

Tags: quantum-spin, time-evolution, spin-models, spin-chains, exchange-interaction

I am trying to simulate the time evolution of a spin in spin chain interacting via Dzyaloshinkii-Moriya interaction. The Hamiltonian is of the form

$$H_{A}=J_{A}\sum_{i}(S^{x}_{i}S_{i+1}^{y}-S^{x}_{i+1}S_{i}^{y})$$

The boundary conditions are open boundary conditions and I initialize the spins in the $x$-direction. What I am observing is that $\langle S_x\rangle$ of the $i$'th spin changes with time while $\langle S_y\rangle$ and $\langle S_z\rangle$ are constant. This doesn't seem right to me as I think that the interaction should try to make the spins perpendicular. Can anyone explain if this is what is to be expected and give a physical intuition of what is exactly happening/should happen?

Comment: Should there be a "does not" or "are constant" after $\langle S_z\rangle$?

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I edited the mistake.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on with $\langle S_y\rangle$, but $\langle S_z\rangle$ is conserved by the DM interaction.

Comment: I know Sz will be conserved cause the Hamiltonian commutes with the total Sz. But since the Hamiltonian is essentially $S_{i} × S_{i+1}$, I assume this term should act like a torque or something and cause a rotation.